Retain IP address when AWS EKS cluster and managed nodegroup is upgraded
We have an EKS cluster version 1.20 and managed nodegroup with a public IP address. When we upgrade the EKS cluster and nodegroup with version 1.21, the managed nodes will start with a new IP address. How can we retain the original IP address?

You cannot assign Elastic IP to specific EKS worker statically, but you can do that dynamically.
Pod definition:
spec:
      hostNetwork: true
      initContainers:
      - name: eip
        image: docker.io/amazon/aws-cli:2.0.18
        command:
        - /bin/bash
        - -xec
        - |
          INSTANCE_ID=$(curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id)
          aws ec2 disassociate-address --public-ip "$PUBLIC_IP" || true
          aws ec2 associate-address --public-ip "$PUBLIC_IP" --instance-id "$INSTANCE_ID"
        env:
        - name: PUBLIC_IP
          value: 
        - name: AWS_REGION
          value: eu-central-1
        - name: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              key: awsKeyId
              name: restund
        - name: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              key: awsSecretKey
              name: restund

AWS privileges:
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:AssociateAddress",
        "ec2:DisassociateAddress"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}

And the secret for the application:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: restund
type: Opaque
data:
  awsKeyId: {key-id}
  awsSecretKey: {secret-key}

Check out this blog for more detail:
https://itnext.io/attaching-an-elastic-ip-to-eks-worker-node-f69b9d8fa521

Please don't post link only answers, they become useless when the link dies. Instead, include the gist of the link in your answer.

While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - From Review
